# Node.js API user request checking function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, postman, cryptojs

my logging API has some problems hard to find that.  register API
working correctly and after checking the postman that was shown my
username password and everything but when I tried to check logging
that showed an empty parameter. What's wrong with my logging function?
I have to install CryptoJS to encrypt the password. please check them.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

//Register
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            req.body.password, 
            process.env.PASS_SEC
            ).toString(),
    });
    try{
        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(savedUser);
       }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});

//Login
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");
    
        const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
            user.password,
            process.env.PASS_SEC
        );
        const password = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        
        password !== req.body.password && 
            res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");

            res.status(500).json(err);
    }catch (err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image: This is screenshop in postman]

Comment: Why do you use `res.status(500).json(err);` at the end of the `try` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last res.status is causing the problem

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");
    
        const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
            user.password,
            process.env.PASS_SEC
        );
        const password = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        
        password !== req.body.password && 
            res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");

            res.status(200).json(user); //This means all the cases are succesfull so you should pass the user(with necessary properties)
    }catch (err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```